Selecting extreme temperature values from pandas dataframe column where selection process includes several complicating conditions
Have weather data set that includes daily high temperature in Celsius in a pandas dataframe that is as simple as the date and daily high temperature (rounded to the tenth value). Here is a sample data set:
data_dict = {
    'dates': ['2023-07-01', '2023-07-02', '2023-07-03', '2023-07-04', '2023-07-05', '2023-07-06', '2023-07-07', '2023-07-08', '2023-07-09', '2023-07-10', '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12', '2023-07-13', '2023-07-14', '2023-07-15', '2023-07-16', '2023-07-17', '2023-07-18', '2023-07-19', '2023-07-20', '2023-07-21', '2023-07-22', '2023-07-23', '2023-07-24', '2023-07-25', '2023-07-26', '2023-07-27', '2023-07-28', '2023-07-29', '2023-07-30', '2023-07-31', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-02'],
    'daily_high_temp': [39.1, 39.8, 40, 40.3, 40.4, 40.2, 40.4, 40.6, 41, 41.1, 40.9, 41.2, 40.9, 39.9, 41.2, 42, 42.3, 41.9, 40.7, 39.8, 41.1, 41.3, 40.9, 40.7, 40, 39.8, 41.2, 40.9, 39.6, 40.9, 41.4, 41.2, 41.4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dict)

Want to create another dataframe column 'extreme_highs' that logs extreme high temps with several conditions. Those conditions:

For dates/temps not logged set value = 0
Only temps greater than 40 degrees Celsius are eligible for logging.
Starting at earliest date, identify temp greater than 40 degrees.
Considering that date/temp and the proceeding 3 days immediately following that date, log the date/temp with the max temp.
If two or more date/temps in the four-day window share the max temp, only log the date/temp in which the max temp first occurred (earliest occurrence)
Once a date/temp has been logged, the next six days are ineligible for logging. Only one date/temp in a seven day period is to be logged.

Based on the data above and conditions listed, the resulting data should be (hopefully) produced:

I have developed a solution to this in excel, but it is convoluted and complicated. Hoping that a simple "pythonic" solution can be shared because I am stumped! Thank you for your help!!!

I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: how-to-ask

@itprorh66 I actually worked hard on this question. It is specific issue I am working through now. Not sure how to make any more specific. I have a good knowledge of Pandas so not looking for general tips. I willingly admit the title to this question could be more targeted, but not sure how to go about better titling. Would appreciate any help. Cheers

Use a sliding window, find argmax and fill accordingly, then shift window.
i = 0
while i < len(df):
    if df.loc[i, 'daily_high_temp'] <= 40.0:
        i += 1
    else:
        max_index = df.loc[i:i+3, 'daily_high_temp'].argmax()
        df.loc[i+max_index, 'extreme_highs'] = df.loc[i+max_index, 'daily_high_temp']
        i += max_index+6+1

df = df.fillna(0)


This is an incredible answer. Thank you! To interpret for others looking at this most excellent answer, pd argmax() is selecting the first index that contains the max. So if multiple values equal the max, argmax() is selecting the first of those index values.
